# Recurse through XML document

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am looking for a good approach to recurse through an XML document without specifying XPATH or XQUERY expressions.  Just starting at the root node.  I need to hold on to the element and the text of the node.

Something similar to:

```
    private void RecurseXml(XmlNode root)
    {
        if (root is XmlElement)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(root.Name);
            if (root.HasChildNodes)
                RecurseXmlDocument(root.FirstChild);
            if (root.NextSibling != null)
                RecurseXmlDocument(root.NextSibling);
        }
        else if (root is XmlText)
        {
            string text = ((XmlText)root).Value;
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

Where the recursion process determines if their are children or not versus using xpath.  The issue with the code I posted is tying the text for the element together.  So I can match on the element name in another process I have and set it equal to the value of the text. So I can use conventions to do the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you don't just want to `XDocument.Descendants()`? I can't remember whether that's breadth-first or depth-first, but it will find all the elements in the document recursively...

Note that your *sample* code uses `XmlElement` and `XmlText`, but your *tag* says `xdocument`. I saw the tag first, which is what led me to think you were using LINQ to XML. If you're *not* using LINQ to XML but could do so, I'd suggest you do that. It's not entirely clear what you really want to do, but if you *just* need to print the text of all elements, that's really easy:

```
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants())
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
}
```

Of course this will write an empty line for "empty" elements - if you want to avoid that, you could just check before writing to the console.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I forgot about descendants and most examples online are using xpath and xquery.